# js match serarching with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, match, innerhtml

I'm trying to get the first date of each 3 names from a list sorted by rows.
The array is dynamic. Without arrays, it works fine...

But from here I can't get it to work. Is there any way to get the array into the match?

```
var array=new Array();
array[1]='name1';
array[2]='name2';
array[3]='name3';

for (var k = 1; k <= array.length; k++) {
    tow = document.getElementById('cal_table');
    zap = tow.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    for (var i=1; i<=zap.length; i++){
        opt0 = zap[i].innerHTML.match(/<td>array[k]<\/td>|<td>.*2012<\/td>/img);
        if(opt0.length==2){
            alert(opt0);
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `array[k]` meant to be a literal string, or the value returned from the array at index `k`? Also, could you show your (relevant/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML structure, and, ideally, a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, live demo would be useful.

Comment: Why are you starting your arrays at index `1` instead of `0`?

Comment: A tip: move `tow` and `zap` outside the loop, it will make the code faster

Comment: Are you asking a) how to get every third element from an array and b) how to use the value of that element to build a regular expression?

Comment: `var array = [undefined, 'name1', 'name2', 'name3'];`  even if you want to do base 1 arrays, array literals are cleaner.

Comment: Also, given that you don't appear to be *using* `tow` anywhere (except to find the `tr` elements) you could just `zap = document.getElementById('cal_table').getElementsByTagName('tr');`

Comment: Thanks for your replies and tips. I have implemented it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the RegExp constructor, i.e. `new RegExp("<td>" + array[k] + "|<td>.*2012<\/td>", "img")`.